# Haskell - Inserting a thread dealy between the results of Prelude.sequence function

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have some code that looks like this

```
  listOfIOByteStrings = simpleHttp <$> apiLinks :: [IO ByteString]
```

where `apiLinks` is a list of links which calls some API function.

I also have this function

```
  z = sequence listOfIOByteStrings
```

`sequence` has this type [sequence :: Monad m => t (m a) -> m (t a)](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.24/base-4.11.1.0/Prelude.html#v:sequence)

What I want to do is add a thread delay between each `ByteString`'s evaluation.

I'm thinking of using `threadDelay` [threadDelay :: Int -> IO ()](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.24/base-4.11.1.0/Control-Concurrent.html#v:threadDelay)

This is what I'm doing ultimately

```
listOfContent <- z
pPrint $ filteredTitles . onlyElems . parseXML <$> listOfContent
```

where

[parseXML :: ByteString -> [Content]](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.24/xml-1.3.14/Text-XML-Light-Input.html#v:parseXML)

[onlyElems :: [Content] -> [Element]](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.24/xml/Text-XML-Light-Proc.html#v:onlyElems)

and

```
filteredTitles :: [Element] -> [String]
```

---

Applying thread-delay between result of sequence would be something like this

```
printing (filteredTitles . onlyElems . parseXML (bytestring of link1))... 
delay of 1 sec...
printing (filteredTitles . onlyElems . parseXML (bytestring of link2))... 
delay of 1 sec...
printing (filteredTitles . onlyElems . parseXML (bytestring of link3))... 
delay of 1 sec...
```

I'm not sure how I should go about doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of way to do that is using `forM_` as

```
...
do listOfContent <- z
   forM_ listOfContent $
         \content -> do pPrint $ (filteredTitles . onlyElems . parseXML) content
                        threadDelay 1000000
```

Comment: That works! Just `pPrint $ filteredTitles . onlyElems . parseXML <$> content` needs to be `pPrint $ (filteredTitles . onlyElems . parseXML) content`. No need to map it over `content` since `content` isn't a list but an element of it.

Comment: @atis yes, you are right, I overlook the type signature of `parseXML :: ByteString -> [Content]` just pass `ByteString` as argument, I shall correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow all the types in your pipeline, so consider this a rough sketch that can be fleshed out. First, you don't want to call `sequence` too early. Keep your list of `IO Bytestring` values for now.

Next, you want some function (defined in terms of `filteredTitles . onlyElems . parseXML`) that takes a *single* `Bytestring` and returns an `IO ()`. If `pPrint` is the write type, this might simply be

```
process :: IO ByteString -> IO ()
process ibs = do
    bs <- ibs
    pPrint (filteredTitles . onlyElems . parseXML $ bs)
```

`map process (apiLinks >>= simpleHttp)` should result in a list of type `[IO ()]`.  That could probably be rewrittn in a less clunky fashion, but *now* we can get to the heart of the answer, which is using `intersperse` to insert your thread delays before finally sequencing the `[IO ()]` to get `IO [()]`.

```
import Data.List
let results = map process (apiLinks >>= simpleHttp)
    actions = intersperse (threadDelay 1) results 
in sequence actions
```

`intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]` works by inserting its first argument between each element of its second. A simple example using strings:

```
> intersperse '-' "abc"
"a-b-c"
```

Comment: `simpleHttp` actually has the type `String -> IO ByteString` so I don't know if `apiLinks >>= (process . simpleHttp)` would work. EDIT: Just checked. Getting this error `• Couldn't match type ‘m0 ByteString’ with ‘ByteString’`

Comment: `pPrint` is just pretty print. `(pPrint) :: (Control.Monad.IO.Class.MonadIO m, Show a) => a -> m ()`